# Why Angular bootstrap not display pagination buttons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

Here I'm using Angularjs bootstrap and Bootstrap. I wanna display Angular pagination, but it does not display.

**Master.html**

```
<script src="../../Script/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../Script/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../../Script/angular-loader.js"></script>
<script src="../../Script/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
```

**Child.html**

```
<h5>Total page{{Employee.length}}</h5>
<pagination total-items="Employee.length" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="pagesize">
</pagination>
```

Comment: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination >> this libray dirPagination helped me to achieve my goal. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please check document https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination

use Pagination as attribute, it is not element, because restrict of pagination   directive is 'A'
Example:

`<ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></ul>`